# Filter by extension in Electron file dialog

Tags: javascript, electron

How do I add a filter by extension in an Electron file dialog. For example:

```
function openDialogExample() {
    var remote = require('remote');
    var dialog = remote.require('dialog');

    return dialog.showOpenDialog(
      remote.getCurrentWindow(),
      {
          defaultPath: 'c:/',
          filters: [
              { name: 'All Files', extensions: ['*'] },
              { name: 'Images', extensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'] },
              { name: 'Movies', extensions: ['mkv', 'avi', 'mp4'] }
            ],
          properties: ['openFile']
      }
    );
}
```

How do I implement it into my codebase?

```
const app = require('electron').remote
const fs = require('fs')
const dialog = app.dialog

document.getElementById('importWallet').onclick = () => {
    dialog.showOpenDialog((fileName) => {
        if(fileName !== undefined) {
            readWallet(fileName[0])
        }
    });
}

function readWallet(filePath) {
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            alert('An error occured while importing your wallet', err)
            return
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I am still not sure what you are trying to do. Do you want to build the options object on the spot?

Comment: Yes, I want to integrate it so that it gets picked up by the instance of the file dialog? Is that the correct way of doing things?

Comment: Ok, my english is not my strong point, so let's talk about it until I get it ^^" Normally you get a dropdown menu where you can choose between the defined filters (which you can name as you like btw.) So you want to add your unicorn filter on the fly because you don't know which kind of files you want the unicorn filter to show until in runtime? (unicorn because I like unicorns xD)

Comment: Yes exactly. Well either way, I would like to filter out all the files in the dialog that dont match my defined filters

Comment: Do you only match by extension (like the standard)? Then you don't have to do the filtering yourself. The dialoge window will only show files that match the choosen filter.

Comment: Sure, but how do I set it up in my codebase? Do you know how to?

Answer (score 5):

You can add as many filters to your options object as you like. You just have to make sure you don't add them more than once - because there is no check on uniqueness.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <button id="importWallet">Import wallet</button>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

index.js

```
const app = require("electron").remote;
const fs = require("fs");
const dialog = app.dialog;

//customize this one as you like
const dialogOptions = {
  defaultPath: "c:/",
  filters: [
    { name: "All Files", extensions: ["*"] },
    { name: "Images", extensions: ["jpg", "png", "gif"] },
    { name: "Movies", extensions: ["mkv", "avi", "mp4"] }
  ],
  properties: ["openFile"]
};

document.getElementById("importWallet").onclick = () => {
  const unicornFilter = dialogOptions.filters.find(item => {
    if (item.name === "Unicorn") {
      return item;
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  });

  if (!unicornFilter) {
    const myUnicornFilter = {
      name: "Unicorn",
      extensions: ["unicorn", "horse"]
    };
    dialogOptions.filters.push(myUnicornFilter);
  }

  dialog.showOpenDialog(dialogOptions, fileName => {
    if (fileName !== undefined) {
      console.log(fileName);
      readWallet(fileName[0]);
    }
  });
};

function readWallet(filePath) {
  fs.readFile(filePath, "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      alert("An error occured while importing your wallet", err);
      return;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: why use a callback with `showOpenDialog` when it returns a promise?

Comment: @BugWhisperer because it didn't a year ago :) but thanks for telling me, I'll update my answer

Comment: ah ok. any idea how i could set the `defaultPath` to This PC on Windows i.e. an overview of all the drives a user may have on their PC?

Answer (score 5):

**step one:** you must send a IPC from (main process) main.js to the (render Process) index.js. for more details [read this](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer), [this](https://xwartz.gitbooks.io/electron-gitbook/content/en/api/web-contents.html) and [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md).

**step two:** now you can processing openFile or openDirectory or ...

**an example (of my code):**

**main.js: (with win.webContents.send(...); i send an ipc)**

```
... after require some library in app.on("ready", () => {
   let appMenu = [
       {
            "label": "file",
            "submenu":
                [
                    {
                        "label": "open file",
                        "accelerator": "CmdOrCtrl+o",
                        click() {
                            showDialog("openFile");
                        },
                    }, // end ofshowSaveDialog "open file"
                    {
                        "label": "save file",
                        "accelerator": "CmdOrCtrl+s",
                        click() {
                            showDialog("saveFile");
                        },
                    }, // end of "save file"
                    {
                        "type": "separator"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "open Directory",
                        "accelerator": "CmdOrCtrl+k+o",
                        click() {
                            showDialog("openDirectory");
                        },
                    }, // end ofshowSaveDialog "openDirectory"
                    {
                        "type": "separator"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "exit app",
                        "accelerator": "CmdOrCtrl+X",
                        "role": "quit",
                    } // end of "exit"
                ], // end of "submenu file"
        }, // end of "file"
    ]
})
function showDialog(typeShowDialog) {
switch (typeShowDialog) {
    case "openFile":
    case "openDirectory":
        dialog.showOpenDialog(
            {
                "title": `${typeShowDialog}`,
                "properties": [`${typeShowDialog}`], // openDirectory, multiSelection, openFile
                "filters":
                    [
                        {
                            "name": "all",
                            "extensions": ["*"]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "text file",
                            "extensions": ["txt", "text"]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "html",
                            "extensions": ["htm", "html"]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "style sheet",
                            "extensions": ["css"]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "javascript",
                            "extensions": ["js"]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "c++",
                            "extensions": ["cpp", "cc", "C", "cxx"],
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "json",
                            "extensions": ["json"]
                        },
                    ],
            }, // end of options: electron.OpenDialogOptions
            (filename) => {
                if (filename === undefined) {
                    return;
                }
                win.webContents.send(`${typeShowDialog}`, filename); // Sending Content to the Renderer Process this is a IPC
            }
        ); // end of "dialog.showOpenDialog"
        break;
    case "saveFile":
        dialog.showSaveDialog(
            {
                "title": `${typeShowDialog}`,
                "filters":
                    [
                        {
                            "name": "all",
                            "extensions": ["*"]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "text file",
                            "extensions": ["txt", "text"]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "html",
                            "extensions": ["htm", "html"]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "style sheet",
                            "extensions": ["css"]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "javascript",
                            "extensions": ["js"]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "c++",
                            "extensions": ["cpp", "cc", "C", "cxx"],
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "json",
                            "extensions": ["json"]
                        },
                    ],
            }, // end of options: electron.SaveDialogOptions
            (filename) => {
                if (filename === undefined) {
                    return;
                }
                win.webContents.send(`${typeShowDialog}`, filename); // Sending Content to the Renderer Process this is a IPC
            }
        ); // end of "dialog.showSaveDialog"       
        break;
} // end of "switch"
```

} // end of "showDialog"

**index.js: (with ipcRenderer.on(...); i receive ipc)**

```
    ipcRenderer.on("openFile", (event, arg) => {
      // some sttements;
});

ipcRenderer.on("openDirectory", (event, arg) => {
     // some statements;
 });

ipcRenderer.on("saveFile", (event, arg) => {
    // some statements;
});
```

[and this is a example about ipc](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/122/Electron-IPC-Tutorial---Communication-within-your-Electron-App)